# Login with Powershell to website, cant find the right fields

Tags: powershell, invoke-webrequest

Im struggling logging in to a website. I did find the form "bs-dummy-login-form" with the following request

```
$Site = Invoke-WebRequest 'https://www.mystique-dummy.eu/login'
$Site
$Site.Forms
$Site.InputFields
```

If i understand it right, are the names of the fields: login and password. I cant find the name of the token. Tried it also with Dev Tools. Seems to be hidden.

My code that i have changed from a previous working script:

```
$LoginUri = "https://www.mystique-dummy.eu/login"
$LoginResponse = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $LoginUri -SessionVariable "Session"
$LoginBody = @{
    authenticity_token = $LoginResponse.InputFields[1].value
    login = "anyemail"
    password = "anypassword"
    submit = "Sich anmelden"
}
$LoginResponse = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $LoginUri -WebSession $Session -Body $LoginBody -Method "POST"

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://www.mystique-dummy.eu/download/csv/feed.csv'  -OutFile '.\feed.csv'
```

It gives a 404. I think the Login has not worked properly. Does anyone have an idea how to solve it? Sorry if i do not find the exact expressions/words, im from Germany.

With kind regards, Alex

Comment: What's the actual problem? What errors did you get? If you can't find the field names, that's not anything that we can help with without seeing the form. I usually right click/inspect to find the field names. What happens if you inspect the variable values at runtime?

Comment: I think the main problem is, that i cant find the name of the authenticity token. It gives a 404.

Comment: 404 is page not found, rather than an auth error. You may need to carefully examine the post when logging in manually then compare the to what happens when you use the script

Comment: After several hours of trying i have solved it now with basic http authentication. Im happy.